# Is there a way to see your tasks from different projects in greenhopper?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

My team is using greenhopper, but I have tasks in different projects because I'm on several teams. Is there any way that I can see my all of my tasks in one place in greenhopper? In Jira I set up an issue filter that showed everything assigned to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Support [for] multiple projects within GreenHopper](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-1800) has been the highest voted feature request in GreenHopper's history and is meanwhile available as of version 5.8, see [Support for multiple JIRA projects on the Rapid Board](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/GreenHopper+5.8+Release+Notes#GreenHopper58ReleaseNotes-SupportformultipleJIRAprojectsontheRapidBoard):

> Teams can now view and transition issues from multiple JIRA projects
>   on the one board, the Rapid Board. On the Rapid Board we have removed
>   the old concepts of Project and Context and introduced a Rapid View.
>   The Rapid View is based upon JQL allowing teams to select only those
>   issues that matter to them.

With the [Rapid Board](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+the+Rapid+Board), the GreenHopper team has crafted a very powerful new architecture based on the [JIRA Query Language (JQL)](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching), which basically aims to make the board fully customizable by building rows, columns and quick filters on top of a respective JQL query.

This is part of a long term product evolution, see [The Future of GreenHopper](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/The+Future+of+GreenHopper) for details:

> In GreenHopper 6.0 we plan to push the existing boards (Planning,
>   Task, Chart and Released Boards) to a Classic Mode and drop the
>   "Rapid" title. The existing functionality on the Planning, Task, Chart
>   and Released Boards will continue to be available for a number of
>   releases until it becomes clear that the majority of customers have
>   switched over.

Please note that the respective functionality of the *Rapid Board* is evolving quickly accordingly, and features are usually introduced via [GreenHopper Labs](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/GreenHopper+Labs) first; in addition you'll need a relatively current JIRA installation, e.g. at the moment [JIRA 4.4.3 is Required](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/GreenHopper+5.8+Upgrade+Notes#GreenHopper58UpgradeNotes-JIRA443isRequired).